# Create Vb.net equivalent of PHP array with multiple values

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create an array in visual basic to store multiple values, i want to do it like in PHP:

```
$arr = array("1" => "one", "2" => "two");
```

then looping through:

```
foreach($arr as $a => $b) {

}
```

what would be the equivalent in VB.net?

Comment: The docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx#BKMK_CreatingAnArray) give a clue: `Dim values As Double() = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`

Comment: i want it to be multidimensional like you can do in PHP so i can store 2 values for each array object

Comment: `Dim a = {{1, 2.0}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}` except you might want a `Dictionary` if you want to do lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a PHP array like:

```
$arr = array("1" => "one", "2" => "two");
```

The VB.Net equivalent is a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`.

Two examples of usage:

```
    Dim dicA As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    dicA.Add("1", "one")
    dicA.Add("2", "two")
    For Each Item As String In dicA.Values
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", Item))
    Next
```

This example uses a collection initializer and is a bit closer to your PHP:

```
    Dim dicB As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"1", "one"}, {"2", "two"}}
    For Each Item As String In dicB.Values
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", Item))
    Next
```